# Question on calculating incoming data from file

Tags: python-3.x

If I am reading a data file with some variable, I need to calculate the total numbers of different items by adding them from different lines. For example:

```
Fruit,Number
banana,25
apple,12
kiwi,29
apple,44
apple,81
kiwi,3
banana,109
kiwi,113
kiwi,68
```

we would need to add a third variable which is a total of the fruit, and fouth total of all the fruits. 
So the output should be like following:

```
Fruit,Number,TotalFruit,TotalAllFruits
banana,25,25,25
apple,12,12,37
kiwi,29,29,66
apple,44,56,110
apple,81,137,191
kiwi,3,32,194
banana,109,134,303
kiwi,113,145,416
kiwi,68,213,484
```

I was able to get the first 2 columns printed, but having problem with the last 2 columns

```
import sys
import re

f1 = open("SampleInput.csv", "r")
f2 = open('SampleOutput.csv', 'a')
sys.stdout = f2
print("Fruit,Number,TotalFruit,TotalAllFruits")
for line1 in f1:
    fruit_list = line1.split(',')
    exec("%s = %d" % (fruit_list[1], 0))
    print(fruit_list[0] + ',' + fruit_list[1])
```

I am just learning python, so I want to apologize in advance if I am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a 2d-array to keep the values read from the input file.
And during the loop, you need to read the value from previous lines, and then calculate the value of the current line.
And print the 2d-array after all input lines read.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use pandas library as it makes your process easier

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("SampleInput.csv",sep=",")
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # change the above to what ever you need
    df2['Totalsum'] = df1['TotalFruit'] + df1['TotalAllFruits']
    df2['Fruit'] = df1['Fruit']

df2.to_csv('SampleOutput.csv',sep=",")
```

df2 format :

```
Fruit    | Totalsum |
---------------------
Name     |  Sum     |
---------------------
```

Feel free to change the number of columns to your needs and add your custom logic.